# The analyzer is unable to determine the position

Tags: c++, winapi

I am getting the following error from PVS Studio
V669 The 'fetch_mask' argument is a non-constant reference. The analyzer is unable to determine the position at which this argument is being modified. It is possible that the function contains an error.

This is the line:

```
XXH64_state_t* hash_state, uint32_t& fetch_mask
```

I was figuring the error was the & isn't part of fetch_mask I fixed it like:

```
XXH64_state_t* hash_state, uint32_t &fetch_mask
```

The error goes away. However, travis.cl test says I need to reformat and fails.

I think found problem original codes.

```
void TextureCache::HashTextureBindings(
XXH64_state_t* hash_state, uint32_t& fetch_mask,
const std::vector<Shader::TextureBinding>& bindings) {
for (auto& binding : bindings) {
uint32_t fetch_bit = 1 << binding.fetch_constant;
if (fetch_mask & fetch_bit) {

void HashTextureBindings(XXH64_state_t* hash_state, uint32_t& fetch_mask,
                       const std::vector<Shader::TextureBinding>& bindings);
```

I removed the & since I think it is supposed to be uint32_t fetch_mask instead of uint32_t& fetch_mask

Comment: What context does this code appear in? That seems really odd.

Comment: I think found solution I removed uint32_t& fetch_mask with uint32_t fetch_mask. I am compiling now to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Error is gone, so I am guessing that was the problem duh. I guess the programmer made an error

Comment: @tadman here is another question I see the code if (32 - (offset + count) > 0) wouldn't it be better to use if (32 != offset + count). in the comments it has // <-- 32 - (offset + count) ------ [bits] -?-

Comment: If you're asking about why your C++ linter complains about things this is a very deep rabbit hole to go down. It appears to be recommending a more consistent and concise way of representing your code. These are all guidelines, not hard rules.

Comment: PVS Studio suggested to use (32 != offset + count) instead of (32 - (offset + count) > 0)

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates, that you are passing a **non-const** reference to a variable into a function, but PVS-Studio is unable to see, whether that variable actually gets modified. The purpose of passing an argument by reference is, that a function can modify the original value. If a function doesn't modify a value passed by reference, that reference should be `const` instead (i.e. `uint32_t const& fetch_mask`).

Passing a variable by value is another way to express, that a function doesn't modify the original value (although I prefer to pass by const value as well, so that it doesn't get accidentally assigned). For integral data types it is common to pass them by (const) value.

The diagnostic is essentially questioning, whether the intended purpose and code match up. The purpose of the code is, that the variable passed through the `fetch_mask` formal parameter can be modified, yet the implementation doesn't attempt to do so (unless it's doing so in a way that PVS-Studio cannot see, e.g. by aliasing it).

---

For reference, here is the official documentation for [V669](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V669/):

> The analyzer has detected that an argument is being passed by reference into a function but not modified inside the function body. This may indicate an error which is caused, for example, by a misprint.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand we are talking about [this](https://github.com/benvanik/xenia/blob/master/src/xenia/gpu/vulkan/texture_cache.cc) code. I’ll write the whole body of a function:

```
void TextureCache::HashTextureBindings(
    XXH64_state_t* hash_state, uint32_t& fetch_mask,
    const std::vector<Shader::TextureBinding>& bindings) {
  for (auto& binding : bindings) {
    uint32_t fetch_bit = 1 << binding.fetch_constant;
    if (fetch_mask & fetch_bit) {
      // We've covered this binding.
      continue;
    }

    auto& regs = *register_file_;
    int r = XE_GPU_REG_SHADER_CONSTANT_FETCH_00_0 + binding.fetch_constant * 6;
    auto group =
        reinterpret_cast<const xenos::xe_gpu_fetch_group_t*>(&regs.values[r]);
    auto& fetch = group->texture_fetch;

    XXH64_update(hash_state, &fetch, sizeof(fetch));
  }
}
```

As you can see, the variable **fetch_mask** is used only for reading in the expression **if (fetch_mask & fetch_bit)**. It is strange to pass an integer variable by reference and not to modify it. This is often a sign that the code contains an error. Yes, it's not always a mistake, but this code should be carefully verified.

For PVS-Studio analyzer it does not matter, if **uint32_t& fetch_mask** or **uint32_t &fetch_mask** is written. In any case, it will issue the warning .

Probably, there is no error here. You can eliminate the warning by removing the link **&** as you did. Another option is to use one of the mechanisms of suppression of false positives.